# nvidia graphic drivers on ubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia

i wanna install the new ubuntu on my new laptop but idk whats will happend with graphic drivers. my laptop is Dell precision m4800 and i have Nvidia K1100 as graphic card on that. can i install and use ubuntu?

Comment: Why not try before you install?  (refer https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install)   This works for all *flavors* of Ubuntu as well

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.

Try removing old one if anything available add repos then try autoinstall the driver finally restart. If worked

> step 1 : sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
>
> step 2 : sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
>
> step 3 : sudo apt-get update
>
> step 4 : sudo apt-get install nvidia-common

check your `softwares and updates` -> `additional drivers`-> change alternatively check it.

=============================================

If not try autoinstall method;

> step 1 : sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

> step 2 : Restart